# How to call Java method on button created in JS/JSNI

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I want to call a Java method on a click of a button which is NOT created as usual in GWT but is created by using plain HTML.

Below is the sample code:-

```
private native void createHeaderSpanContents(Element element)/*-{

element.innerHTML='<button type="button" onclick="this.@ca.bell.nis.psp.client.gui.AbstractSearchResultGrid::hideColumns()()"></button>Identification';
```

}-*/;

```
public void hideColumns() {
    // Hide the columns
}
```

The above way of calling hideColumns() Java method from within JSNI does not work here. Please help!

Regards,
-Trans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Button.wrap()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.html#wrap%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element%29) to make a `Button` out of an `Element`, e.g.:

```
Button b = Button.wrap(Document.getElementById("foo"));
b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
    hideColumns();
  }
}):
```

Comment: Hey Jason! Thank you very very much. You made my day. The approach suggested by you works!